# Ubuntu 16.04 with Titan X and Asus X99-A II (initramfs) Unable to find a medium

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, system-installation

After selecting install Ubuntu, installation halts after [13s] at ... priv:GPC0: ... and (initramfs) : unable to find a medium, etc...

My guess is that this comes from incompatibility with NVIDIA's Titan X GPU.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

removing **quiet splash** from syslinux.cfg seems to do the trick.
I also kept changing terminals (ctrl+alt+f?) during the splash screen.